# Gibt's in diesem Kontext einen wesentlichen Unterschied zwischen „versandt“ und „zurückgesendet“?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, vocabulary, difference

Ich habe neulich mein Handy von Google reparieren lassen, und auf der Statusseite steht folgendes:

[image]

Wie soll ich das deuten?  Ich bin kein Muttersprachler, aber das ergibt für mich keinen Sinn. Gibt's eine Nuance oder einen Unteschied zwischen "versandt" und "zurückgesendet", den ich nicht verstanden habe?

Und ja, ich habe Google selbst schon gefragt!  Ich frage euch nur, um die Sprache besser zu verstehen :-)

Comment: Wilkommen auf german.SE :) Was hat Google dazu gesagt?

Comment: Da lässt sich bestimmt die Sprache umstellen. Englisch dürfte die Originalsprache sein, in der eine verständliche Meldung steht. Daran könntest du erkennen was tatsächlich gemeint ist.

Comment: @puck Leider scheint es, dass sich die Sprache nicht unabhängig von der Region (Währung, Adressen, etc.) umstellen lässt. Bisschen ärgerlich... Sonst hätte ich schon das Ganze auf Englisch umgestellt!

Comment: From context and my own experience, *versandt* is "shipped", meaning the item is now in transit; Google has given it whoever is actually transporting it to you. Then *zurückgesendet* is "delivered", meaning there's no reason to be checking the page because the item should be sitting on your doorstep.

Comment: @WillVousden Im Browser kann man auch die gewünschte Sprache einstellen, vielleicht spielt die Seite dabei mit.

Comment: Und was hat Google geantwortet?

Comment: @PaulFrost Nach einer Ewigkeit ist das Paket endlich angekommen.  Google war nicht super hilfreich, aber es hat sich herausgestellt, dass das Paket schon versandt wurde, aber UPS hatte mit der Lieferung irgendwie versagt.  Ich habe keine Tracking-Nummer bekommen, also wusste ich überhaupt nicht, was da vor sich ging.

Comment: Du hast Recht, ich habe es geschafft, indem ich der URL `&hl=en-GB` hinzugefügt habe. Auf Englisch lautet es "Not yet delivered". Andererseits hat's sich noch nicht geändert, obwohl es jetzt geliefert wurde.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Zurückgesendet* verstehe ich in diesem Kontext gar nicht. Das wäre nur sinnvoll, wenn sie das Gerät nicht oder unvollständig repariert hätten und sich auf eine Rücksendung/Reklamation einstellen (- das würden sie aber sicher nicht auf die Statusseite stellen).

Wahrscheinlich handelt es sich um eine falsche Übersetzung. Zu dem Zeitpunkt könnte *zugestellt* oder *geliefert* passen, oder die *Rückmeldung über erfolgten Empfang* gemeint sein.

Comment: Die Abwertung der Antwort ist unpassend.

Comment: "Zugestellt" heißt es bei Amazon, BTW: lassen sich Übersetzungen in den USA patentieren?

Comment: @Wolf: "Zugestellt" bedeutet aber Erfolg, also nicht das gleiche wie zurückgesendet.

Comment: @userunknown ich habe keinen Zweifel daran, finde es nur bemerkenswert, dass Google selbst Übersetzungsdienste anbietet, das aber anscheinend in der Firma nicht bekannt ist? https://translate.google.de/?ui=tob&sl=en&tl=de&text=repaired%2C%20shipped%2C%20delivered&op=translate

Answer (score 2):

Ein Paket oder Brief kann man ***versenden***, ***verschicken*** bzw. ***absenden*** oder ***abschicken***.
(Vom Absender zum Empfänger)

Wenn ein Paket oder Brief nun an den Absender ***zurückgesendet*** oder ***zurückgeschickt*** wird, kann das auch ***retournieren*** oder ***remittieren*** genannt werden.

Der Ablauf, der auf der Statusseite zu sehen ist, ergibt für mich aber eher wenig Sinn, außer die Meldung "*Noch nicht zurückgesendet*" wird bei Ankunft des Pakets bei dir (dem ursprünglichen Versender, aber jetzigen Empfänger) auf "*zurückgesendet*" geändert.
Dies würde dann bedeuten, dass die Firma das Paket *aktuell* zwar **versendet**, aber das Paket noch nicht abschließend **zurückgesendet** wurde.

Nach meinem Verständis hat das Wort **"zurücksenden"** diese "Bedeutung der Abgeschlossenheit" aber nicht unbedingt inne. (D.h man kann ein Paket auch zurückgesendet haben ohne, dass es wirklich schon angekommen sein muss.)

- aktueller Status: **versandt**
- zukünftiger Staus (*bei Ankunft bei dir*): **zurückgesandt**/zurückgesendet (Versand an den ursprünglichen Versender abgeschlossen)

Answer (score 1):

Es handelt sich nicht um ein Sprachproblem. Der Unterschied zwischen "verschickt" und "zurückgesendet" ist offensichtlich, es gibt da keine tiefere Ebene, die ein Muttersprachler besser klären könnte. Die Diskrepanz müsste jemand aufklären, der tiefere Kenntnisse über die Funktion von Googles Trackingsystem hat.

Das ist einfach eine schlechte Benutzeroberfläche. Daten aus verschiedenen Softwaresystemen, die verschiedene, inkompatible Sprechweisen benutzen, werden schlecht in einer Oberfläche zusammengeführt. Das kann zum Beispiel das Warenwirtschaftssystem von Google sein, dessen Daten mit Tracking-Daten von verschiedenen Paketdiensten zusammengeführt werden. Die Paketdienste benutzen wiederum ein leicht unterschiedliches Vokabular.

Der eine Teil der Software nennt das Versenden der reparierten Waren an den Kunden "zurücksenden", der andere Teil nennt es "verschicken", der eine Teil hat eine andere Definition von "zurückgesendet" oder "verschickt" als der andere - zum Beispiel gilt die Ware beim einen als verschickt, wenn die in die Filiale eingeliefert wurde, beim anderen, wenn das Paketauto sie abgeholt hat, und beim dritten, wenn jemand einen Paketaufkleber gedruckt hat. Dann steht vielleicht im Warenwirtschaftssystem, die Ware sei noch nicht verschickt worden, aber im Tracking steht sie schon als verschickt drin, oder umgekehrt. "Zurückgesendet" ist auch eine Vokabel, die sich je nach System auf völlig verschiedene Meilensteine innerhalb des Rücksendevorgangs beziehen kann.

Es ist wenig sinnvoll, sich da tiefe Gedanken über die Nuancen der Sprache zu machen. Die Informationen sind einfach inkonsistent, und zwar in einer Weise, dass man die Inkonsistenz ohne weitere, interne Informationen über die Funktionsweise des Systems nicht auflösen kann.

Answer (score 0):

Der Unterschied zwischen *zurücksenden* und *versenden* ist, das ersteres unterstellt, dass das Gerät schon mal bei Dir war, das zweite dies zwar nicht ausschließt, aber offenlässt.

Der Zeitleistencharakter der Grafik legt aber nahe, dass wir hier einen 3stufigen Ablauf haben:

- reparieren
- versenden
- zurücksenden

und dass die Angelegenheit im Moment Status 2 verlassen aber 3 noch nicht erreicht hat. Das wirkt nicht konsistent, denn zwischen dem Versenden und Zurücksenden wird sich der Adressat ja nicht mehr ändern.

Inhaltlich würde eine Unterscheidung zwischen *Absenden* und *Ausliefern* Sinn ergeben, wenn der Versand und die Übergabe protokolliert werden, wie es bei teurer Hardware oft üblich ist. Erklärbar wäre das mit nachlässiger Übersetzung, aber das ist natürlich eine Spekulation.

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt hier keinen Unterschied zwischen „versandt“ und „zurückgesendet“. Allerdings führt die Verwendung zweier verschiedener Begriffe zu Irritation. Besser wäre es meines Erachtens, auf der Statusseite entweder

- "Versandt [Datum]" und "Noch nicht versandt"

oder

- "Zurückgesendet [Datum]" und "Noch nicht zurückgesendet"

anzuzeigen.

Für den Kunden ist die Bedeutung des Status "noch nicht zurückgesendet" (unterhalb des ausgegrauten Felds) möglichweise unklar und kann sogar zu Misverständnissen führen. Der Grund für diese Statusoption dürfte ein intern bei Google verwendetes Workflowsystem sein. Auch werden die drei Punkte vermutlich nicht von links nach rechts (im Sinne eines Zeitstrahls) durchlaufen. Meine Hypothese:

1. Anfangs ist der Status auf "noch nicht zurückgesendet" gesetzt. Gemeint ist "von Google noch nicht an den Kunden zurückgesendet", d.h. der Repaturauftrag liegt vor bzw. ist in Bearbeitung. Aus Sicht des Kunden ist das natürlich missverständlich, weil er das vermutlich als "von mir noch nicht an Google zurückgesendet" interpretieren wird.
2. Nach Reparatur wird zusätzlich "Gerät wurde repariert" markiert.
3. Bei Versand wird "noch nicht zurückgesendet" durch "Versandt [Datum]" ersetzt.

Falls ich Recht habe, würde ich gerne den Status auf "Von Google schlecht gemacht" setzen ;-)

PS. Vgl. auch den Abschnitt *Nach Eingang des Geräts bei einem Reparaturservice* auf der [Google Support Website](https://support.google.com/store/answer/9004345?p=same_unit_repair&visit_id=637425561318739437-731854803&rd=1). Zitat: "Nach Abschluss der Reparatur erhalten Sie eine E-Mail mit der Information, dass die Reparatur abgeschlossen ist und Ihr Gerät an Sie zurückgesendet wird."